# ParseException: Encountered "/" content.xml for list type

Tags: java, freemarker, odt, parseexception

I was trying to generate a PDF from an existing ODT template with list fields.

My ODT template looks like the following.
[image]

And I have a method to get ByteArrayOutputStream object for further processing.

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream execute(Map<String, Object> data, byte[] templateData) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream odt = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        DocumentTemplateFactory documentTemplateFactory = new DocumentTemplateFactory();
        DocumentTemplate template = documentTemplateFactory.getTemplate(new ByteArrayInputStream(templateData));
        template.createDocument(data, odt);
        return odt;
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    }
}
```

Here the parameter `templateData` is the byte array of the ODT template file and the parameter `data` contains the data object `row` which were added by

```
MyRow row = new MyRow();
row.setCol1("1");
row.setCol2("2");
row.setCol3("3");
row.setCol4("4");
List<MyRow> rows = new ArrayList<MyRow>();
rows.add(row);
data.put("row",rows);
```

When the flow reaches the `createDocument` method above, it causes the following exception.

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "/" at line 4, column 13223 in content.xml.
Was expecting one of:
<STRING_LITERAL> ...
<RAW_STRING> ...
"false" ...
"true" ...
<INTEGER> ...
<DECIMAL> ...
"." ...
"+" ...
"-" ...
"!" ...
"[" ...
"(" ...
"{" ...
<ID> ...

at freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:4697)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:4568)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.UnaryExpression(FMParser.java:323)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.MultiplicativeExpression(FMParser.java:435)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.AdditiveExpression(FMParser.java:385)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.RangeExpression(FMParser.java:556)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.RelationalExpression(FMParser.java:538)
at freemarker.core.FMParser.EqualityExpression(FMParser.java:476)
...
```

I am not able to view the content.xml as it is in byte array format. Is there a way to identify the issue here?

Comment: If you have control over the method `execute` in your snippet, then try first to store the content of the byte array in a temporary file and have a look inside.

Comment: @SubOptimal Something like this?? `FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
     new File("Template.odt"));
   IOUtils.write(templateData, output);`

Comment: Yes. Something like this. Then have a look inside `Template.odt`. It's actually a ZIP file (assuming the templateData is a ODT file). Look in the `content.xml` at the failing position. Maybe this already shows what's wrong or at least would point in a direction for further investigation.

Comment: @SubOptimal how can I see `content.xml`.. i tried to view the value of content.xml in the `template` variable using debug mode, but all i can see is a big array of codes..

Comment: You need to open `Template.odt` with a ZIP file viewer or `unzip Template.odt`. It should contain a `content.xml` file. Then you open the `content.xml` file with an editor and check `at line 4, column 13223`. Check here for information about the [ODT file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument_technical_specification).

Comment: Are you using http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/?

Comment: hi.. sorry. this issue was a problem with the template which I had found out later.

Answer (score 1):

Here the solution:

1) Extract the file content.xml from your odt document (just add the zip extension to the filename)
2) Open the xml file with a text editor
4) Search for all of the fields name you have specified in the template

For example if you use the standard FreeMarker expression notation and you have added the field ${MYPLACEHOLDER} to the template, you could see some xml code like this:

```
...<text:span text:style-name="T4">${MYPLACEHOLDER}</text:span>...
```

but other times, and it's the case you have reported, you could find the following xml code:

```
...<text:span text:style-name="T4">${</text:span></text:span><text:span text:style-name="Character_20_Style_20_1"><text:span text:style-name="T5">MYPLACEHOLDER</text:span></text:span>...
```

where your custom field syntax is splitted (see the dollar character).

What's the cause ?

Sometimes the user could format the document with OpenOffice or LibreOffice in the wrong way, splitting the formatting styles of the field palceholder. 
That situation could not be visible inside the visual editor.
So the best strategy could be to write a document without formatting it, add the fields, and then apply the formatting.

Regards from Italy